# Unable to inject factory into directive

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular and am doing some experimenting.  I want to create a factory that hits various YouTube API endpoints and then use that factory within a directive.  But I keep running to this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: YouTubeAPIProvider <- YouTubeAPI uploadVideoButtonDirective
```

Here is the directive:

```
var app = angular.module('MobileUploader', []);

app.directive('uploadVideoButton', ['YouTubeAPI', function(YouTubeAPI) {
  return {
    //SOME CODE HERE
  }

}]);
```

Here is the factory:

```
var app = angular.module('MobileUploader', []);

app.factory('YouTubeAPI', ['$http', function($http) {
    return{
        //SOME CODE HERE
    }
}]);
```

I've looked through the documentation and other posts and can tell that this error relates to an injection issue.  For the life of me I can't figure out what is wrong with my code.  I'm specifying the app as such:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="MobileUploader">
```

For simplicity's sake I've removed the code from both the factory and the directive.  I don't think the code I've removed could be the issue because the error is saying it can't find the factory.  Right?  Maybe I'm just missing something really obvious here...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is the way you are using modules. `var app = angular.module('MobileUploader', []);` will create a new module (set). While `var app = angular.module('MobileUploader');` will retrieve an existing module (get). So you have to remove `, []` on your second call and it should work as you just need to create a module once.

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't work.  Does it matter that these code snippets are saved in separate files?

Comment: Usually, we put the code in separate files, so it should not be a problem.

Comment: I did a plunker with the modifications and it works: http://plnkr.co/edit/HChYfl8HVKrbzqUrh62n?p=preview. Did you look at the dev console if there is no javascript error?

Comment: Thanks for the plunker.  I see what I did wrong now.  Would you add your plunker as an answer so I can accept it?  Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way you are using modules.

```
var app = angular.module('MobileUploader', []);
```

will create a new module (set). While

```
var app = angular.module('MobileUploader');
```

will retrieve an existing module (get). So you have to remove `, []` on your second call and it should work as you just need to create a module once.

Live Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/HChYfl8HVKrbzqUrh62n?p=preview

(from the question's comments)

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module('MobileUploader', [])    
app.factory('YouTubeAPI', ['$http', function($http) {
    return{
        //SOME CODE HERE
    }
}]);
app.directive('uploadVideoButton', ['YouTubeAPI', function(YouTubeAPI) {
  return {
    //SOME CODE HERE
  }

}]);
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VliawbX4zbENPn8lgfNk?p=preview)